# Clipping Elements in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a picture using TikZ in LaTeX. In this example, I have drawn two curved lines and a vertical line. I would like to make the lower curved line only visible to the right of the vertical line. In other words, I would like to clip the lower curved line. However, I do not want to clip the entire picture. I would still like to view the entire top curve. Is this possible in TikZ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\draw (.1,1.6) .. controls (.6,1.6) and (1.5,1) .. (2,1);
\draw (.1,1) .. controls (.6,1) and (1.5,.4) .. (2,.4);
\draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Tom I changed the question slightly to more clearly indicate that I didn't want to clip the entire picture, but just the one curve. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `\clip`command inside a scope:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]

\begin{scope}
    \clip(1,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (.1,1.6) .. controls (.6,1.6) and (1.5,1) .. (2,1);
\end{scope}

\draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Only the things in the scope are clipped:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\draw (.1,1.6) .. controls (.6,1.6) and (1.5,1) .. (2,1);

\begin{scope}
    \clip (1,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (.1,1) .. controls (.6,1) and (1.5,.4) .. (2,.4);
\end{scope} 

\draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops let me delete mine :)

Comment: @percusse: same idea, and also around immedeately? I know that feeling ;)

Comment: @Tom Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: To only clip in a single direction, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149523/153678