# Trim excessive whitespace from top of 3d pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using the data in [this file](http://pastebin.com/aJX53bu6), I have the following plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            view = {95}{40},
            zmin = 0,
            restrict z to domain = 1:,
            axis x line = left,
            axis y line = left,
            axis z line = right,
        ]
            \addplot3 [draw=black, mark=none] table {biomass.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

I would like to trim off the extra whitespace at the top, like so:

[image]

My guess is that the graph adds extra space at the top in case I want `z` axes all around, but the extra space shows up even though I don't need the top-left one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using clipping seems to be the right solution. Also see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49039/clipping-elements-in-tikz) on using clipping.

Your MWE would then become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-0.5, -1) rectangle (15, 19)
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.9\textheight,
            view = {95}{40},
            zmin = 0,
            restrict z to domain = 1:,
            axis x line = left,
            axis y line = left,
            axis z line = right,
        ]
            \addplot3 [draw=black, mark=none] table {biomass.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You will have to find the right parameters for the clipping, but after that it should work like a charm. Consider using negative vspace (\vspace{-10mm}) if you want to move the whole a bit higher.

Comment: The MWE works for me. Did you use the data file I provided? http://pastebin.com/aJX53bu6

Thanks for the suggestion of `\clip`, it seems to work pretty well. It looks like `\clip (-0.5, -1) rectangle (15, 19)` are the best parameters for me.

Comment: My apologies, I missed the file entirely. Since \clip worked, I assume the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, more or less. There is still some manual position adjustment to be made, but `\clip` solves this specific question.