# Why the shift in tikz doesn't work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I like the ring diagram, so I want to use a kind of ring diagram in my document. Thank Jack for the answer Ring Diagram(https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake). However when I use the code in my document, the diagram isn't at a fine position. So i want to xshift it. However the command xshift doesn't work! What hapened?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.cm}
\def\outerradius{2cm}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
% Calculate total
\pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
\foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
    \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}
    \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
  \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=2.5cm];
  % Rotate so we start from the top
  \begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm,rotate=90]%%here I want to xshift

  % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

        % Calculate the percent value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
        % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

        % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
        \pgfmathparse{
           (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
        } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

        % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
        \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
        (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

        % Draw the data labels
        \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\name: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%};


        % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
        \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
    }

  \end{scope}
  \clip (-0cm,-2.5cm) rectangle (5cm,2.5cm);%there should be some problems but the tikz ignores it, why?
  %\draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\wheelchart{26/cyan/Corporate,  28/orange/Plastique, 33.5/yellow/Chimique, 12.5/blue!50!red/Rhodia}

\end{document}
```

xshift=0cm
[image]

xshift=-2cm
[image]

These 2 pictures above are the real outputs after I change the `xshift` paragram(where?  **`\begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm,rotate=-90]`**). So why? Thank you for reading and answers. I had installed the texlive 2017.

I want the colored circle to shift along x-axis. The length can be decided by me. Because my document has two columms like this.
[image]

The colored circle now is at the left column, however I want to move it to the right column like this;

[image]

In this way, there are some mistakes which you can see in the picture above.I tried to xshift,but it failed. And last night I took advice and used the `\clip` to fix my problem. But Why does `xshift` not work as I want?(move towards left)

Comment: The shift for scopes has only an effect it you have another object inside your `tikzpicture` outside the `scope`. Otherwise - as in your case - this will not have any visible effect.

Comment: You should probably try the `\clip`-command to reduce/add whitespaces and you might want to think of using a float. Compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49039/clipping-elements-in-tikz#49040.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh thanks a lot for your comment. In fact, my document has two columns. The diagram is at a too left position, so that it only has the left half in the page and the right half disappears. So I want to add some xshift(eg. xshift=-1cm), however it doesn't move at all.

Comment: @CampanIgnis I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I did like this:`      \end{scope}
\clip (-3cm,-2.5cm) rectangle (5cm,2.5cm);...` and `      \end{scope}
      \clip (-0cm,-2.5cm) rectangle (5cm,2.5cm);...` I noticed that the output pictues were the same.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If I want to move the tikzpictures against the layout of a page, How should I implement it?

Comment: @BO.LI AS far as I understand your comment, you have not understand the other post. You need to add the `\clip`-command before the objects you want to clip (read the fine manual). You could also try `\clip[draw]` the first times you use this command.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thanks a lot for advice, the `\clip`-command does work for my problem.

Comment: positioning of your image in a text had to be set outside of picture. For example ` ... \begin{center} ... your image ... `end{center} ...` if you like to have centered. if you like to shift, than use `\hspace{<desired amount> }`. Frankly said, i don't understand well, what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko I want the colored circle xshift towards the left and the red circle doesn't move, however the red moves right and the colored doesn't move. In fact I want to the text and the colored circle are closer.and the red circle doesn't move.

Comment: how you now this? I'm afraid that your expectation are wrong. To see, what is mowing, you should fix one node regarding to page border (not recommend) . otherwise, all is relative (to some starting coordinate). To be honest, I still not understand, what you like to achieve. Any version of `shift` command works.

Comment: @Zarko please look the post which I have edited. I want just to move left the picture to some length. However it doesn't move at all. Oppositely the red(reference) which should not have move at all should  move right. I believe it interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that everything outside the tikzpicture adds space the the left or right of the tikzpicture.  I added some code to draw the bounding box, then removed the extra spaces until the bounding box matched the edges of the standalone.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.cm}
\def\outerradius{2cm}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{%
% Calculate total
\pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}%
\foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {%
    \pgfmathparse{\value+\totalnum}%
    \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}
  \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=2.5cm];
  % Rotate so we start from the top
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90]%%here I want to xshift

  % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
  \foreach \value/\colour/\name in {#1} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \value/\totalnum*360}

        % Calculate the percent value
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\value/\totalnum*100}
        % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

        % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
        \pgfmathparse{
           (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
        } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{1-2*(-\midangle>180)}

        % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
        \fill[\colour] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
        (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

        % Draw the data labels
        \draw  [*-,thin] node [draw,append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at (\midangle:\outerradius + 1ex) [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=\textanchor]{\name: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}\%};


        % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
        \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
    }

  \end{scope}
  \draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  %\clip (-0cm,-2.5cm) rectangle (5cm,2.5cm);%there should be some problems but the tikz ignores it, why?
  %\draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\wheelchart{26/cyan/Corporate,  28/orange/Plastique, 33.5/yellow/Chimique, 12.5/blue!50!red/Rhodia}%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

If you want to center the origin inside the bounding box, you can use the following (either before, after or instead of drawing the bounding box).  It requires the `calc` tikzlibrary.

```
\path ($(current bounding box.south west)!2!(0,0)$);
\path ($(current bounding box.north east)!2!(0,0)$);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can fix my problem. And I found it was the extra spaces that disturbed me. I compared your code and my previous code. I found nothing but the line `\draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` So where is your magical code ?

Comment: Every line that ends with { or } adds a space, whereate {% and }% do not.  Also, I moved \begin{document} back as far as possible.